# Calculate number of nodes from numbers of arcs in a tree - Induction

Tags: induction

If a tree has k arcs, how many nodes does it have?

Base case:

```
If k=0 => n=(k+1)=1
```

Inductive hypothesis: `For every k, n=(k+1) is true`

Proof:

```
Is it true for k=1?
k=n-1
1=n-1
1=(k+1)-1
k=1,so:
1=1+1-1
1=1
Proved?
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure mathematics problem, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

**You never want to use 0 or 1 as your base case for proof by induction**

```
If k=0 => n=(k+1)=1
```

You can prove anything you want if you use 0 (or often 1) as your base case. The classic example of this being that [all horses are the same color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color). This is your mistake.

In addition, you can make graphs with the same number of arcs have different numbers of nodes, *which immediately shows that you are not going to be able to use proof by induction to solve your problem.*

Good luck!